# When to use raw strings in regex patterns?

Tags: python, regex

From the documentation on [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) I understand that it's recommended to use "raw" strings for patterns to make sure backslashes are not handled in any special way:

> Regular expressions use the backslash character (`'\'`) to indicate
>   special forms or to allow special characters to be used without
>   invoking their special meaning. This collides with Python’s usage of
>   the same character for the same purpose in string literals; for
>   example, to match a literal backslash, one might have to write `'\\\\'`
>   as the pattern string, because the regular expression must be `\\`, and
>   each backslash must be expressed as `\\` inside a regular Python string
>   literal.
>
> The solution is to use Python’s raw string notation for regular
>   expression patterns; backslashes are not handled in any special way in
>   a string literal prefixed with `'r'`.

I wonder what other cases (apart from the literal backslash) may require using raw strings?

Comment: Pretty much anything that can be interpreted as a Python string escape sequence... no?

Comment: It useful when dealing with paths, on Windows at least... e.g. "C:\Users\Me\Desktop" may not behave as desired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One another example is sequences like `\1`, `\2` which are octal escapes in Python strings, but reference captured groups in regular expressions.

```
>>> re.search(r"(\w+) \1", "the the")
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 7), match='the the'>
>>> re.search("(\w+) \1", "the the")
>>>
```